# How to create layout for tower made of blocks

Tags: java, layout, grid

I have a tower built from blocks like this :

[alt text http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/654/boxlayout.png](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/654/boxlayout.png)

Whole Tower is an array of Towers. Each Tower contains Box[] array containing single Box'es.What layout should I use for this and can you give me any tips on how to create it ?

Would it be easier if I would create Grid[][] containing Box'es? But I guess I can't store Box object inside Grid array. I'm just totally confused :/

Comment: Wordy.  Fix please >_< i'm confused.

Comment: Also, reference your other questions on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a good time to clearly separate you [view and model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller). Your model might have methods like `nextMove()`, `getRow()` and `getRowCount()`, while your view might consist of `JTextField` instances in a `GridLayout` for each row and multiple rows in a `BoxLayout`. The view asks the model about its current state; the model notifies the view when updates occur. This [game](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/) was intended as a concrete example of the approach.